# Error message for HTTP image sometimes flows over into preview

Tags: bug, design, editor, ssl

When editing a post with an embedded HTTP image ([example](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/28237/edit)), you'll see an error message asking you to upload it to imgur or specify an HTTPS URL:

[image]

However, the lack of a line break after the image in [this revision of a post on Webmasters Stack Exchange](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/revisions/1659/1) makes the second sentence flow into the preview:

[image]

You can check it yourself by starting to edit [this Sandbox post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/318427/295232), since the Webmasters post is now locked.

Comment: I think it is that the text is on the same line as the image. It works when adding a line break.

Comment: @MEEthesetupwizard correct, that seems to be the culprit.